# How to implement a battle function in a text based game written in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am making a text based adventure game in jQuery and i would like to implement a battle function where if there is an enemy in the room you are in you can say "attack enemy" and you and the enemy trade attacks until someone dies. if you have a weapon then your attack is buffed

I tried to write this fight function

```
    function fight(en) {
  if(rooms[currentRoom].enemys[en]!== undefined) {
    $('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms[currentRoom].enemys[en] + "</p>");
    if(stats[user].hp > 0 || stats[en].hp > 0) {
      //user attacks
      stats[en].hp -= stats.user.attack;
      alert(stats.en.hp);
    }
    else {
      $('#game-text').append("<p>You can not fight here</p>");
    }
  }
}
```

right now when that function is called it will the message that is linked to the enemy from this line `$('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms[currentRoom].enemys[en] + "</p>");`
however, it will not alert the health.

here is the code that seems relevant.

```
 switch(command) {
    case "go":
        var dir = input.split(" ")[1];
        changeRoom(dir);
        break;
    case "help":
        showHelp();
        break;
    case "inventory":
        showInventory();
        break;
    case "take":
      var item = input.split(" ")[1];
      takeItem(item);
      break;
    case "fight":
      var en = input.split(" ")[1];
      fight(en);
      break;
    default:
        alert("invalid move!");
  }

function fight(en) {
  if(rooms[currentRoom].enemys[en]!== undefined) {
    $('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms[currentRoom].enemys[en] + "</p>");
    if(stats[user].hp > 0 || stats[en].hp > 0) {
      //user attacks
      stats[en].hp -= stats.user.attack;
      alert(stats.en.hp);
    }
    else {
      $('#game-text').append("<p>You can not fight here</p>");
    }
  }
}

var stats= {
  "user" : {
    "hp" : 10,
    "attack" : 2
  },
  "troll" : {
    "hp" : 9,
    "attack" : 1
  }
}
```

here is the html:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Text Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans+Condensed:400,400i,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  </head>
  <body>

      <div id="game-text">
        <h3> Welcome to My Text Based Adventure!! </h3>
     </div>
    <input id="user-input"placeholder="Enter Commands"> </input>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"> </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="rooms.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect the output to be an alert with the health but that never happens

```js
/* fix me, how am I called? */
switch (command) {
  case "go":
    var dir = input.split(" ")[1];
    changeRoom(dir);
    break;
  case "help":
    showHelp();
    break;
  case "inventory":
    showInventory();
    break;
  case "take":
    var item = input.split(" ")[1];
    takeItem(item);
    break;
  case "fight":
    var en = input.split(" ")[1];
    fight(en);
    break;
  default:
    alert("invalid move!");
}

function fight(en) {
  if (rooms[currentRoom].enemys[en] !== undefined) {
    $('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms[currentRoom].enemys[en] + "</p>");
    if (stats[user].hp > 0 || stats[en].hp > 0) {
      //user attacks
      stats[en].hp -= stats.user.attack;
      alert(stats.en.hp);
    } else {
      $('#game-text').append("<p>You can not fight here</p>");
    }
  }
}

var stats = {
  "user": {
    "hp": 10,
    "attack": 2
  },
  "troll": {
    "hp": 9,
    "attack": 1
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Text Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans+Condensed:400,400i,600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="game-text">
    <h3> Welcome to My Text Based Adventure!! </h3>
  </div>
  <input id="user-input" placeholder="Enter Commands"> </input>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js">
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="rooms.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `alert` is wrong; `en` is dynamic, so you need  `alert(stats[en].hp);`

Comment: Are `en` and `user` variables or object properties? In your condition, you treat them as variables `stats[user].hp` then treat them as properties afterward `stats.user.attack` and `stats.en.hp` Did you intend to do that?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML so we can actually test.

Comment: Your code as posted is not functional with that random `case` there - please provide a functional set of code per https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: One warning
30 Missing semicolon.
Four undefined variables
8 rooms
9 rooms
8 currentRoom
9 currentRoom
9 $
16 $
10 user
One unused variable
7 fight

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Added HTMl, sorry about that

Comment: @trincot I changed the alert to your suggestion however it still does not alert, i think that this if ```if(stats[user].hp > 0 || stats[en].hp > 0) {``` is never triggering

Comment: What is the value of `user`? Is it supposed to be a variable? Or did you mean `stats.user.hp`?

Comment: @trincot user is an object in var stats(i think)
```var stats= {
  "user" : {
    "hp" : 10,
    "attack" : 2
  }```

Comment: I edited to add a snippet of your question, adding a comment re: the switch.  I did NOT attempt to fix the malformed HTML in the header re: link elements.

Comment: Owen, in that case you should never write `stats[user]` but `stats.user` (or `stats["user"]` if you want)

Comment: that fixed the alert! thank you @trincot. I am now going to figure out a loop to put in the if statment